# Small $N$ ideal gas entropy and extensive entropy: Finite $N$ Sackur-Tetrode and Gibbs Paradox

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

In the standard derivation of the [Sackur-Tetrode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sackur%E2%80%93Tetrode_equation), the accounting for the indistinguishability of ideal gas molecules adds an extra factor of $N!$ in the partition function. This is usually approximated by Stirling's approximation.

Let us assume that the volume of the box is very large so that the energy spacing is very small, so we can replace the sum in the partition function with a Gaussian integral. Then the entropy of a monoatomic gas without the large $N$ assumption is exactly
$$S= Nk\left[\log(n_Q V)+\frac{3}{2}\right]-k \log N!,$$
where $n_Q=\left(2\pi m k T/h\right)^{3/2}$ is an intensive quantity.

We can expand the Stirling series,
$$S= Nk\left[\log(n_Q V)+\frac{3}{2}\right]-k \left(N \log N-N +\log\sqrt{2\pi N}+\mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{N}\right)\right).$$
The normal resolution of the Gibbs paradox is given by the truncation of the entropy at the leading order,
$$S= Nk\left[\log(n_Q)+\log \frac V N+\frac{5}{2}\right]+ k \log\sqrt{2\pi N}+\mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{N}\right),$$
for which the term in the square brackets is extensive as one scales $N$ and $V$ simultaneously. It is said that this is how indistinguishability resolves the Gibbs paradox, so that entropy remains extensive. However, it is manifest that the subleading corrections do not scale properly.

What happens to the smaller terms at finite $N$? Does this mean the Gibbs paradox isn't fully resolved, or don't we have extensive entropy? The more physical question might be, if we did an experiment with extremely dilute gases where $N$ is small, can we detect a non-extensivity? If not, where does this calculation break down?

Comment: I don't quite get your question. Are you asking if there is a relation like the Sackur-Tetrode equation at small $N$?

Comment: No, the first equation above is already the exact analogue for Sackur-Tetrode for small $N$. The issue is that according to this formula entropy of the gas is not extensive, e.g. if you double $N$ and $V$, $S$ doesn't double.
In the standard textbook derivations of Sackur-Tetrode, only the leading terms of the Stirling approximation are kept, which are indeed extensive. This approximation is used to explain the Gibbs paradox. The explanation does not seem to hold at small $N$ though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is given in the third remark at the end of Section 3 of my paper "Demonstration and resolution of the Gibbs paradox of the first kind" [Eur. J. Phys. 35 (2014) 015023](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/35/1/015023)  (freely available at [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.4638)).

In short, let's assume you combine two subsystems S1 and S2, each with N indistinguishable particles, by removing a partition between them. As a result, you get a new System S with 2N particles. The entropy of S is a little bit larger than the sum of the entropies of S1 and S2, because, after the removal of the partition, there is an uncertainty about how many particles are in each of the two subvolumes. (For example, there could be N+1 particles in the first subvolume and N-1 in the second. Before the removal of the partition there were, per definition, exactly N particles in each subvolume.) For this reason, the entropy of an ideal gas of indistinguishable particles (as a function of T, V and N) is only approximately extensive, but not exactly.

Comment: I see, you're basically claiming that the difference is the entropy for each half mixing into the other half. The precise difference is $k \log (2^N)-k\log \binom{2N}{N}$ which you say goes to zero by Stirling's.
Thanks, this resolves the first subleading correction to the entropy.


However, you still invoked Stirling's so your argument doesn't account for the sub-subleading corrections, i.e. the difference is still not precisely zero for small $N$. For example when $N=1$, the difference is $k\log 2$. So my question isn't fully resolved.

Comment: If we calculate the Shannon entropy of the binomial distribution of size $2N$, $\Delta S=-k \sum p \log p = -k\sum_m \binom{2N}{N}2^{-2N} \log \left(\binom{2N}{N} 2^{-2N}\right)$, the dominant term is indeed the entropy difference we are seeking. So the "surprise" of finding the $2N$ system split perfectly into $N+N$ gives is the entropy, so is the claim then the residual difference $k\log 2^{2N}-k\log \binom{2N}{N}$ is the surprise of finding the system in other configurations like $(N+1)+(N-1)$ etc.?

Comment: Oh, this is right. I think the difference is just the conditional entropy of finding the system in such a $N+N$ state.

Comment: Your last (third) comment suggests that you got it and that your first and second comment are no longer relevant. Nevertheless, regarding these two obsolete comments, I want to remark that the term ${2N}\choose{N}$ only appears in expressions concerning distinguishable particles, such as in my cited paper (where "distinguishable" means that interchanging two particles leads to a new microstate). However, your question refers to indistinguishable particles.

Comment: Yes, I agree your paper uses distinguishable particles, but the residual difference I was referring to is still has a $\binom{2N}{N}$ for indistinguishable particles. Taking the first equation of my original post as a given, $S(2N,2V)-2 S(N,V)= 2Nk \log 2 - k \log (2N)! + 2 k \log N! = k \log 2^{2N} - k \log \binom{2N}{N}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the term ${2N}\choose{N}$ can also appear in the context of indistinguishable particles, as you have shown.

Having reread your second comment, I'm not sure whether I fully understand your interpretation with regard to the binomial distribution, its entropy and its dominant term. Here are two (somewhat informal) interpretations of mine: 

[see following commet..]

Comment: First interpretation: When the subvolumes are divided, there is no uncertainty (i.e., zero entropy) with regard to their particle numbers, because each subvolume has exactly N particles per definition. When the partition is removed, the probabilty distribution of the particle number is given by the binomial distribution $p(m)={{2N}\choose{m}}\frac{1}{2}^{2N}$ (where $m$ be the particle number of the first subvolume). The entropy of this binomial distribution is approximately $\frac{k}{2}\ln\left(\pi e N\right)$, which is approximately $S\left(2N,2V\right)-2S\left(N,V\right)$.

Comment: Second interpretation: When the subvolumes are undivided, the probability of finding exactly $N$ particles in each subvolume is given by ${{2N}\choose{N}}\frac{1}{2}^{2N}$ (this is the dominant term in the binomial distribution). That is, the undivided system has $1/\left[{{2N}\choose{N}}\frac{1}{2}^{2N}\right]$ times more microstates than the divided system. Therefore the entropy difference between both systems is $k\ln\Omega_{\textrm{undivided}}-k\ln\Omega_{\textrm{divided}}=-k\ln\left[{{2N}\choose{N}}\frac{1}{2}^{2N}\right]$, which again equals $S\left(2N,2V\right)-2S\left(N,V\right)$.